# How to catch validation failure with laravel when using form requests

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel

I'm using a formrequest file with laravel 5.2 to check input. This form i'm calling using jquery's $.post function. In my console, it's return **422 Unprocessable Entity** which I suspect to be coming from the response since i'm not formatting it to json. One way of doing [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34760819/249956)

I'd would like to know how I can invoke from my form request, the means to change the output messages to json.

Thanks!

UPDATE 1

JQuery looks like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="csrf-token"]').val()
    }
});

$("#changePassword").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {};
    data.name = $("input[name='name']").val();
    data.surname = $("input[name='surname']").val();
    data._token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    $.post('url',data).done(function(data){
        $(".message").empty().html("Done!");
    }).fail(
        function(response, status){

        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Could you post the code for you `$.post` section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the response method in your request class like below

```
    /**
     * Get the proper failed validation response for the request.
     *
     * @param  array  $errors
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function response(array $errors)
    {
        return Response::json([
            'error' => [
                'message' => $errors,
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Right approach I ended up implementing it as:

return response()->json([]);