# How to show the errors if there are validation errors? (in an ajax post request)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create a multi-step form using jQuery anad AJAX.

In step 1, the user needs to insert personal info: name, surname, etc. When the user clicks  "go to step 2", I send an AJAX post request to the controller method `storeUserInfo()` to validate the user's information.

My question is, how do I use the AJAX error function to display validation errors if they occur?

PaymentController `storeUserInfo()` method:

```
public function storeRegistrationInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
    //dd($request);
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ...
    ]);
}
```

// step 1 and step2 html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <h6>User Info</h6>
    <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
         {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
        </div>
        <!-- other form fields -->
        <input type="submit" id="goToStep2" href="#step2"
                class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix tabs hide" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <form method="post">
            <h6>Payment method</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="paymentmethod1" value="option1" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                        <span class="mr-auto">payment method 1</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="credit_card" value="option1">
                    <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                        <span class="mr-auto">Stripe</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right">
            <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary prev-step">
                Go back to step 2
            </button>
            <button type="button"  data-nexttab="#step3" href="#step3"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn ml-2 next-step">
                Go to step 3
            </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

AJAX code:

```
var page_form_id = "step1form";

$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '{{ route('products.storeUserInfo',$id) }}',
        data: custom_form.serialize(),
        datatype: 'json',

        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            setTimeout(function () {

            }, 3000);
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });

    });
});
```

// jquery to navigate between steps:

```
$(".next-step").click(function(e) {
    var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
    nextTab($active);
});

$(".prev-step").click(function(e) {
    var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
    prevTab($active);
});

function nextTab(elem) {
    elem.parent().next().removeClass('disabled').find('a.nav-link').click();
}

function prevTab(elem) {
    elem.parent().prev().find('a.nav-link').click();
}
```

I have a `errors.blade.php` file with the content below. In forms where I don't use AJAX, I just use `@include('includes.errors')` to display the errors, but I don't know if the AJAX request can also use this.

`Errors.blade.php`:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Google search https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/showing-request-validation-errors-when-submitting-form-by-ajax?page=1 you have to parse from json. In error callback.

Comment: Thanks. I add this to the error handling "error: function (data) {
                        var errors = '';
                        for(datos in data.responseJSON){
                            errors += data.responseJSON[datos] + '<br>';
                        }
                        $('#response').show().html(errors);
                    }". But when "go to step 2" is clicked it appears "jquery.min.js:4 POST http://store.test/product/1/payment/storeUserInfo 422 (Unprocessable Entity)"

Comment: Hmmn mabe csrf token ?

Comment: No I have it "<form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
                                            {{csrf_field()}}...".

Comment: That 422 error just appear if there are validation errors, but instead of the validation errors appear in the response div it appears that 422 error.

Comment: Oh soz didn't see that. Found a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137946/laravel-ajax-422-unprocessable-entity-even-when-token-is-matching solved by checking validator fail an returning response manually.

Comment: Do you know why in the controller appears    undefiend variable $validator in  "if ($validator->fails()) {"?

Comment: Did you define it ? Or put as method injection ?

Comment: Thanks, now it appears "jquery.min.js:4 POST http://store.test/product/1/payment/storeUserInfo 500 (Internal Server Error)" when "go to step 2" is clicked independently if there are validation errors or not.

Comment: I add the validator in the method parameter like "        public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169466/discussion-between-jacktur-and-jake).