# Ajax call to a controller in laravel : error code 422

Tags: laravel

i am trying to make an Ajax call to a controller in laravel and i am getting an error code 422.

This is my controller call :

```
Route::Post('/contact', 'PatientsController@store');
```

and insert the store function i have this some validations

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#form-data').submit(function (event) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

         var _token= $('input[name=_token]').val();
        var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
        var doctor = $('#doctor').val();
        var date = $('#date').val();
         var reason = $('#reason').val();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/contact', // This is what I have updated
            datatype : "application/json",
            contentType: "text/plain",
            data: {                 
                '_token': _token, 
                 'fullname': fullname,
                'doctor': doctor,
                  'date': date,
                'reason': reason,
            }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: It's worth a try to have a look in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137946/laravel-ajax-422-unprocessable-entity-even-when-token-is-matching#answer-34760819

Comment: I think you have some required fields in your database, that is why the error is showing, can you show us your console?

Comment: 422 is natural response code for invalid data. Check all the values you are passing through data. Take the `_token` value like this `"{{ csrf_field() }}"`. And ajaxSetup is not necessary in Laravel, it's already done there.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure just you declared

```
{{ csrf_field() }} or @csrf
```

inside form .

After this hit like this below :

```
$('#form-data').submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent from unwanted page reload.
    $.ajax({
       method: "post",
       url: '{{ route('routeNamehere') }}', // you can call {{ url("/urlHere")}}
       dataType : "json",
       contentType: "text/plain",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success:function(response){
          // some code for response
       },
       error:function(error){
          // some code for error here
       }      
     })
 });
```

## Your done and Fail process also ok.

Comment: thanks for the response... but i got this message                                    
 {message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: {fullname: ["The fullname field is required."], doctor: ["The doctor field is required."],…}
message: "The given data was invalid."

Comment: @Gaiya can you share your form html code plz ? also controller